# How do Jack's dopplegangers work?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

How does their aggro work? Do they attack the closest enemy or the weakest or strongest?

How does their damage stack up to yours? Is it the same or a percentage?

Do they use grenades if you have any grenade ammo?

What gun do they use? In a certain slot or the one equipped when they spawn?

Do they run out of ammo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does their aggro work?

assuming aggro means weather they attack first or wait to be attacked, They attack first, ask questions later.

> Do they attack the closest enemy or the weakest or strongest?

Closest Enemy to them and will stay on that specific enemy till it's dead even if other enemies are physically closer to any one of them.

> How does their damage stack up to yours? Is it the same or a
>   percentage?

Clearly there is no way to know the exact answer to this, but I'm assuming as you level up, your damage level increases, and they level up as well. It wouldn't make much sense for them to do 30 damage on enemies when you're at level 25.

> Do they use grenades if you have any grenade ammo? What gun do they use?

There's a skill On My Mark, that makes Digi-Jacks also throw grenades simultaneously with the Doppelganger (once per skill activation) -edited

> In a certain slot or the one equipped when they spawn?

the one equipped when they spawn

> Do they run out of ammo?

No.

Comment: There's a skill **On My Mark**, that makes Digi-Jacks also throw grenades simultaneously with the Doppelganger (once per skill activation).